# Inside a partial view, on ajax link click update partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that has partial view

**Main view**

```
....
....
@if (Model.ProvidedResponseCount > 0)
{
    <div id="providedTimes" data-url="@Url.Action("ProvidedAttendeeResponse", new { attendeeId = @Model.AttendeeId })">

    </div>
}
....
....
```

And this is the **partial view**

```
....
....
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var times in Model.ProvidedDateTimes)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @times.StartDateTime &nbsp; to &nbsp; @times.EndDateTime
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteResponse", new { id = @times.ResponseId})</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
....
....
```

and the delete method actionlink calls in controller

```
public void DeleteResponse(int id)
{       
    _responseRepository.DeleteResponse(id);      
}
```

Whenever I click the actionlink in the partial view, I am forwarded to different link.
For example, `localhost/Response/DeleteResponse/2`. Something link that.

But I want to stay on the same page, just want the partial view to be updated.

What should I do?

Would `Ajax.Actionlink` help?

I don't have much experience with Ajax.ActionLink, can anyone suggest what should I do?

**Things I tried**

1. `@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteResponse", new { id = @times.ResponseId }, new AjaxOptions ())`
2. `@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteResponse", new { id = @times.ResponseId }, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId="dummy"})`

then in controller

```
public ActionResult DeleteResponse(int id)
{

    _responseRepository.DeleteResponse(id);

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Both didn't work still redirects me to new url.

3. `@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteResponse", new { id = @times.ResponseId }, new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "update"})`

   $(function update() {
           alert("hello");
           var url = $("#providedTimes").data('url');
           url = url + "&t=" + new Date().getTime();

   ```
       $.get(url, function (data) {

           $('#providedTimes').html(data);
       });
   });
   ```

This keeps on alerting hello infinite times.

Edit 2:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteResponse", new { id = @times.ResponseId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="dummy",OnBegin = "begin",OnComplete="complete",OnFailure="fail",OnSuccess = "success"})



$(function begin() {
        alert("begin");
    });
    $(function complete() {
        alert("complete");
    });
    $(function fail() {
        alert("fail");
    });
```

I get alert **begin**, then **complete** then **fail**, all twice when i load the main view, and when I click delete button on partial view it redirects me to different route.

Now when I click delete I get console error:
[image]

Comment: The `Ajax.ActionLink` would be your best solution, besides a jQuery POST. If you don't specify a `UpdateTargetId` in the `AjaxOptions`, then it should keep you on the same page and not modify anything. However, adding a class on your "delete" links and an event listener could also work. You could then make a POST using jQuery.AJAX.

Comment: You can try this inside the `<td>`: `@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteResponse", new AjaxOptions())`.

Comment: I did that but it still redirects me to different url. May be I need OnSuccess inside ajaxoptions?

Comment: Change your action to: `public ActionResult DeleteResponse(int id){       
_responseRepository.DeleteResponse(id); return new EmptyResult();}`. Inside the ActionLink change `new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "dummy" }`. In your partial, at the end, add an empty/hidden `<div>`. I'm sure there must be straight forward solution for this, but this has to work...

Comment: still redirects me to another link. I tried OnSuccess call a function and in that function update partial view again but that didn't work too. This is the Html generated for the code you gave `<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#dummy" href="/Response/DeleteResponse/9">Delete</a>`

Comment: Check if you have "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" loaded in your project.

Comment: it is, and also no console error

Comment: My final suggestion wold be to change your action back to how it originally was and test again...

Comment: In your second options, you haven't mentioned about passing the id to action in controller. this is what i did `@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteResponse", new { id = @times.ResponseId }, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId="dummy"})` am i doing it wrong?

Comment: I didn't specify any because there wasn't a need to update any elements. The code seams ok, I can't really say what's not working...

Comment: @AndreiV Could you see my Edit 2: may be you can get some idea then

Comment: The code seams to be Ok. I sorry, I can't find what's wrong or a way of getting around your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do following check:

**1. I guess you have allready added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

- Make sure it get's loaded for the page. check through firebug.
- Try adding it at the bottom of the page.
- If using MVC below version 4, enable unobtrusive javascript in your web.config.

**2. Apart from above, I didn't see holder for @Ajax.ActionLink**

```
   @Ajax.ActionLink(
    "load partial view", 
    "Delete", 
    "DeleteResponse", 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }
   )
```

Holder

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I have loaded jquery unobtrusive ajax javascript. But my when I put alert on OnFailure event. it gets called. Must mean that something somewher is failing.

Comment: can you look at the console error? I have posted a image

Comment: It seems that compatible issue. also is your jquery library at top before any other library or code? If its already try chaning the jquery version since I have worked with juqery 1.9.1 with unobtrusive-ajax.